# How to use the remove-emoji library in Python?

Tags: python

Anyone know how to use the [remove-emoji library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remove-emoji/0.0.2) in Python?

Documentation details or any solid code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Follow the link that you provided to the library.
2. Extract the contents of the archive.

You'll notice that there is only one function in the entire library;

```
def remove_emoji(text):
    text = text.decode('utf8')
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text).encode('utf8')
```

The only thing you need to do to use this library is call `remove_emoji` with the text you wish to have the emoji removed from.

For libraries like this with no documentation but only one simple task, the best thing you can do is look at the source code. Even in larger libraries, the source code is the only point of truth.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but not completely. But I'm still better off than 30 mins ago. :D